SPNEGO authentication is not working when when Test Third Party Cookie Phaseout flag is enabled
Our java application internally used by our company is deployed in Websphere. It's accessed directly in Chrome browser(first party context) or inside another application(different domain) in a iframe(third party context).  It uses SPNEGO authentication for SSO.
When flag  'test-third-party-cookie-phaseout' is enabled in Chrome, the authentication fails in third party context with message 'SPNEGO authentication is not supported on this client'.
The authentication still works in first party context.
From the websphere trace log, the websphere is sending 401 challenge but browser is not sending SPNEGO token in the failure scenario.
Any one having similar issue with flag  'test-third-party-cookie-phaseout' ? I will appreciate if anyone can provide any setting that I can try ?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
